# Is it possible to interact with SSO between Website A and Website B?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, iframe, single-sign-on

I have a portal called A , known as [www.aone.com](http://www.aone.com), which has several users.
I have a portal called B ([www.btwo.com](http://www.btwo.com)). This portal also has users.

Now I want that, log in with portal A, and add one button, and when we click on that button, we can access portal B.

**Note: Both portals have the same authentication details.It means both users maintain same username and same password**

How can I figure it out?

If I add an Iframe in Portal A , an iframe URL is of Portal B.
and I authenticated the user also. but both portals have their different session timeout, also the condition is that from the iframe, the user can not see the login or logout page.

Comment: The only answer is "it depends"...on a lot of factors about the implementations of the two apps. You refer to "single sign on"...that's something you can use if both apps share the same identity provider which they use for authentication of users. If you simply have two websites which have their own authentication systems, and you happen to have accounts on both of them where you've chosen the same username and password in each one, then that's not SSO. You _might_ be able to automate logging into B once you've logged into A, but the feasibility and details depend on lots of (to us) unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have 2 completely different systems for these 2 websites, as in, what you're describing is that each website has its own account storage and logging mechanisms and the only common thing is that the account's information is the same.

To have a common/shared SSO session you need a centralized Identity Provider(IdP) that handles all the authentications and issues cookies/tokens for the said session. The websites can then also verify the sessions against this IdP

This in turn means that your websites/systems must trust the IdP.

If you log in from one site into the other you will get 2 sets of session cookies, if you *automatically* do this then you risk opening up other vulnerabilities.